How to avoid single block formatting when exporting DataFrame to CSV?
I'm facing an issue when exporting a DataFrame to a CSV file using df.to_csv() in pandas. The content in one of my DataFrame columns is multiline text, but when I export it to a CSV file, the entire text block gets written into a single cell without proper line breaks, resulting in an unreadable format.
For example, this is the kind of content I'm dealing with, and I expected it should be like this:

But after exporting with the following code:
df.to_csv('Findcomposer_updated.csv', index=False, quoting=pd.io.common.csv_quoting.QUOTE_ALL, encoding='utf-8', sep=',', line_terminator='\n')

It shows

I want the CSV to properly reflect the multiline structure as it appears in the DataFrame, with line breaks, so that each section of the text appears on a new line within the same cell.
For a quick example, my exported csv should be
Column:    Genre People Content
First row: Fruit Mark   The fruit is a peach. 
                        It is very delicious.
Second row: Animal Kiki The animal is a dog.
                        It is very cute

But it would be
Column:    Genre People Content
First row: Fruit Mark   The fruit is a peach. 
Second row              It is very delicious.
Third row: Animal Kiki The animal is a dog.
Fourth row:              It is very cute


What does the actual CSV look like; the text content? Is it wrong somehow, or does Excel just mess up parsing it?

We might also benefit from seeing how your DataFrame is being constructed - check out How to make good reproducible pandas examples

@deceze The df should be like what I've expected.(I've updated the post)

As suggested above, please provide df as a constructor. E.g. use df.head().to_dict(), tweak it a bit to create a minimal sample (as with your 'Fruit & Animal' example). Then assign the result to a var. Like: data = {'Genre': ['Fruit', 'Animal'], ...}, adding df = pd.DataFrame(data). Next, for the actual generated CSV output (based on your new sample), indeed provide the text content. I.e., open the csv with something like notepad (not Excel) and post that as csv = '''Genre,People''', etc., keeping the multiline structure as it is.

Likely the data is in a single cell, but the CSV format doesn't indicate to Excel the column and row widths to display it properly.  You have to adjust the widths.
Example:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Genre': ['Fruit', 'Animal'],
                   'People': ['Mark', 'Kiki'],
                   'Content': ['The fruit is a peach.\nIt is very delicious.',
                               'The animal is a dog.\nIt is very cute.']})

df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)

output.csv:
Genre,People,Content
Fruit,Mark,"The fruit is a peach.
It is very delicious."
Animal,Kiki,"The animal is a dog.
It is very cute."

output.csv opened in Excel (no adjustments):

After manual column, row, and alignment adjustments:

Now you can save it in a format that records formatting such as .xlsx.
